# Second Partial Derivative of Compound Function of two variables

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

Given the function to differentiate: $f\left ( u(x,y),v(x,y) \right )$

Where,

$\left\{\begin{matrix}
u=xe^{-y}\\ 
v=y
\end{matrix}\right.$

How do I calculate $\frac{\partial ^{2}f}{ \partial x \partial y}$ in terms of the same notation?

Does anyone have any idea?

Comment: $$f_{x} = f_{u} u_{x} + f_{v} v_{x} \implies f_{xy} = f_{uu} u_{x} u_{y} + f_{u} u_{xy} + f_{vv} v_{x} v_{y} + f_{v} v_{xy}$$

Comment: Use the chain rule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We know that:

$\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x}=\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial u} \dfrac{\partial u}{\partial x}+\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial v}\dfrac{\partial v}{\partial x}$

$\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial y}=\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial u} \dfrac{\partial u}{\partial y}+\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial v}\dfrac{\partial v}{\partial y}$

So, you can now rewrite the main problem like below:

$\dfrac{\partial^{2}f}{ \partial x \partial y}=\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x}(\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial y})=\dfrac{\partial}{x}(\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial u} \dfrac{\partial u}{\partial y}+\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial v}\dfrac{\partial v}{\partial y})$

$=\dfrac{\partial}{\partial u}(\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial u} \dfrac{\partial u}{\partial y}+\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial v}\dfrac{\partial v}{\partial y}) . \dfrac{\partial u}{\partial x}+\dfrac{\partial}{\partial v}(\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial u} \dfrac{\partial u}{\partial y}+\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial v}\dfrac{\partial v}{\partial y}) . \dfrac{\partial v}{\partial x}$